# Identify this quickly spreading plant

Tags: identification, weeds

It is moving into my perennial garden from the woods and I would like to know if I should try to get rid of it or will in grow and allow my perennials to survive. Can I get rid of it? It is moving very quickly into the garden.

[image: what is this]

Comment: Where are you in the world? If in the Great Lakes region, it could be wild lily of the valley (Maianthemum canadense). This is a wildflower, not a weed. It can spread quickly if happy. If it is Maianthemum, it will bloom in the next two or three weeks. The flowers resemble the old fashioned lily of the valley, except that they're not bells.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

If the soil in that area is usually damp, it might be Calla palustris, a rhizomatous perennial plant, but it does like damp or even wet soil and prefers shade. Common name Bog Arum, flowers between June and July https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calla

It's best to remove this because it may well advance into your perennials - but you will find the soil is likely full of rhizomes, and all will need to be removed. Alternatively, you could make a trench between where you don't mind it growing and where you don't want it to grow, removing the rhizomes to keep the trench clear. You can then regularly take a mattock or sharp spade and chop through the rhizomes to stop its progress when they appear at the side of the trench, in the same way as some people manage bamboo.

Comment: I am in New Hampshire and the soil isn't damp and it is in a sunny area. When I looked up Calla it does resemble it, possibly it is false lily of the valley. In any event I plan to make a trench as you have suggested to keep it at bay and in the woods.
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Lily of the Valley...it is all one very long and tangled root system. The entire area must be dug out. Very hardy and very hard to kill, but will transplant very easily.